# How could I use Content.ItemIndex in Code behind ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater

I have this code on ASPX

```
<div class="col-md-8 col-sm-12 text-poster-box">
                        <p tabindex="1">
                            <asp:Label ID="LabelResultName" CssClass="h3" runat="server">Name: <%# Eval("Name") %>  </asp:Label>
                        </p>
                        <p tabindex="2">
                            <asp:Label ID="LabelResultPrice" CssClass="h3" runat="server">Price: <%# Eval("Price") %>$  </asp:Label>
                        </p>
                        <p tabindex="3">
                            <asp:Label ID="LabelResultSalePrice" runat="server" CssClass="h3" Visible='<%#Eval("SalePrice").ToString() != "" ?  true : false %>'>New Price: <%#Eval("SalePrice")%>$</asp:Label>
                        </p>
                        <p tabindex="4">
                            <asp:Label ID="LabelSize" CssClass="h3" runat="server">Size: <%# Eval("Size") %></asp:Label>
                        </p>
                        <p tabindex="5">
                            <asp:Button ID="ButtonRemove" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-primary-c wishlist" Text="Remove" OnClick="ButtonRemove_Click" />

                        </p>
                        <p tabindex="6">
                            <asp:Label ID="lblListNumber" Text='<%# Container.ItemIndex%>' runat="server" Visible="true" /></td>
                        </p>


                    </div>
```

and i would like to use the number given by `Content.ItemIndex` in Code Behind so I could remove from `List<T>` of objects like this:

```
MyList.RemoveAt("value received from Content.ItemIndex")
```

I have no clue if this is even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use onitemcommand for the repeater.
For example:

```
<asp:Repeater id="rptYourPages" runat="server" onitemcommand="rpt_ItemCommand">
```

Then add CommandArgument with an Eval for the ID of the record to the button.

```
 CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ProductID") %>'
```

Your Button code would look like this:

```
<asp:Button ID="ButtonRemove" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-primary-c wishlist" Text="Remove" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ProductID") %>' />
```

You don't need the OnClick.

In the code behind file:

```
protected void rpt_ItemCommand(object source, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
{
    string sProductID = e.CommandArgument.ToString(); 
    // Write your logic here...
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Great! Didn't think of that!  Thanks a lot, I made it work exactly with your suggestion.